# How to call setState method of a parent component after updating child component's state?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component that has a child component. The child component has many checkboxes. onClick of every checkbox turns the state of the checkbox as true and the whole component is updated. On every click of `checkbox`, I need the label of the checked checkbox in the parent component so I pass a function from Parent to the child component. In `componentDidUpdate()`, when I call function passed from parent through props, it works perfectly fine. At the moment, I get updated state of child component i.e. labels of checked checkboxes and I can see them  through console.log. But if I, instead of using `console.log()`, use `setState({SelectedLabels:selected})`, it goes into infinite loop and after a few moments an error is shown: Maximum limit exceeds. I searched a lot. React documentation says that you must not call `setState()` in `componentDidUpdate()`, componentWillUpdate and even `shouldComponentUpdate()`. Can somebody tell me where can I use this then?
Here is my code:

**Parent component:**

```
    class BuildingsModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    breadcrumbEntries: [{ title: "World" }],
    disabled: true
  };

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
// This is my function that goes to child to get run after child gets updated so the received array can be used to set the disabled state of this component. If I do not call setState of this component and only console.log() function, it work fine. There is an issue with the state update. Please help!! 
  handleSelectedItems = selectedArray => {
    selectedArray.length > 0 && this.setState({disabled:false});
      console.log(
        "SelectedArray:",
        selectedArray,
        "disabled",
        this.state.disabled
      );
  };

  render() {
    const { fullScreen } = this.props;
    const { open, breadcrumbEntries, disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <PageHeader
          title="Dashboard"
          subtitle="33 Irving Place, New York, NY 10003"
          icon
          onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
        />
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          scroll="body"
          fullScreen={fullScreen}
          maxWidth="sm"
          PaperProps={{
            style: {
              paddingLeft: 77.5,
              paddingRight: 77.5,
              paddingTop: 20,
              paddingBottom: 44,
              borderRadius: 23
            }
          }}
        >
          <DialogHeader>
            <Title>33 Irving Place</Title>
            <DialogActions>
              <LinkButton onClick={this.handleClose} type="danger">
                Cancel
              </LinkButton>
              <LinkButton onClick={this.handleClose} type="success">
                Save
              </LinkButton>
              <LinkButton onClick={this.handleNext} disabled={disabled}>
                Next
              </LinkButton>
            </DialogActions>
          </DialogHeader>
          <ContentWrapper>
            <Breadcrumb
              entries={breadcrumbEntries}
              getIndex={index => console.log("index is: ", index)}
            />
            <Content type="world" getSelectedItems={this.handleSelectedItems} />
          </ContentWrapper>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BuildingsModal;
```

**Child Component:**

```
class Contents extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      checkedItems: new Map(),
      filteredItems: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    var filteredItems = [];
    const filterItems = (value, key, map) => {
      value === true && filteredItems.push(key);
    };
    this.state.checkedItems.forEach(filterItems);
    this.props.getSelectedItems(filteredItems);
  }

  getWorldData() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        "United State",
        "United Kingdom",
        "China",
        "Korea",
        "Japan",
        "Pakistan",
        "India",
        "Bangladesh"
      ]
    });
  }

  getCountryData() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        "New York",
        "Los Angeles",
        "Chicago",
        "Houston",
        "Phoenix",
        "Philadilphia",
        "Dallas",
        "Reno"
      ]
    });
  }

  getBuildingData() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        "33 Irving Place",
        "22 Irving Place",
        "11 Irving Place",
        "3344 Irving Place",
        "44 Irving Place",
        "77 Irving Place",
        "55 Irving Place",
        "66 Irving Place"
      ]
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { type } = this.props;
    type === "world"
      ? this.getWorldData()
      : type === "country"
        ? this.getCountryData()
        : type === "building"
          ? this.getBuildingData()
          : alert("No Data to show");
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const label = e.target.value;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(label, isChecked)
    }));
  }
  render() {
    const {
      data,
      checkedItems
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <Content type={data === null ? "progress" : null}>
        {data === null ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size={100} />
        ) : (
          <FlexColumn>
            {data.map(item => (
              <Label
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={checkedItems.get(item)}
                    value={item}
                    color="default"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                }
                label={item}
                key={item}
              />
            ))}
          </FlexColumn>
        )}
      </Content>
    );
  }
}

export default Contents;
```

May be some of you suggest me that why do I need to call the function, coming from the prop, in `componentDidUpdate()` and not when in `handleChange(e)`. **Answer to it:** when I setState of child component, it is not immediately updated so I cannot call the function, passed through props, with the updated state. I need the updated state to be sent through this function. Help me please guys!

Comment: There is one pattern in reactjs. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). It will solve many problems.

Comment: Thanks @Gobinda, it was worth knowing and helper to resolve my issue!

Comment: Most welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function:

```
handleChange(e) {
    const label = e.target.value;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(label, isChecked)
    }));
  }
```

Try calling the passed in prop function:

```
handleChange(e) {
const { getSelectedItem } = this.props;
    const label = e.target.value;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    getSelectedItems(label, isChecked);
  }
```

Your child components should be either "stateless" or a "PureComponent" and should essentially have limited to no logic or state in them. You pass everything in using props, redux, Mobx, etc or the new context API Provider/Consumer technique. I encourage you to google some of these terms.

*** Key take away from the link shared above ***

There should be a single “source of truth” for any data that changes in a React application. Usually, the state is first added to the component that needs it for rendering. Then, if other components also need it, you can lift it up to their closest common ancestor. Instead of trying to sync the state between different components, you should rely on the top-down data flow.

Comment: Your try method makes sense to me after I've gone through the pattern, [Lifting State Up] (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), suggested by @gobinda above. Thanks both of you.